# Scrapy - use website's search engine to scrape results

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have to go through the results of a search on a website. The thing is that the URL doesn't change when you search for something on that site, meaning that I can't use the URL to have the results that I want to have.

My question is, can Scrapy set the filters that I need, search for the results, and then go through all the results of the search ?

If yes, how ? And if not do you know something that could do it using Python or something else ?

Thanks

Comment: Care to share what have you tried!!

Comment: Share your code

Comment: I've not coded anything yet since I am trying to know if it's doable. The filters are checkboxes and dropdown menus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the search term is not reflected in the URL, it means that it is transmitted to the server as a POST reqest. This means that your Scrapy code also needs to make a POST request in order to submit the desired search term.

The [Scrapy request documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-to-send-data-via-http-post) has examples for making a POST request, simulating a form submission:

```
return [FormRequest(url="http://www.example.com/post/action",
                formdata={'name': 'John Doe', 'age': '27'},
                callback=self.after_post)]
```